# Translation Question—isse?

Tags: translation

いっせのせでふみこむゴウライン。

"Isse no se de fumikomu gourain"

*gourain here means *goal line*

The translation for the sentence above is "(All) together (now), make a break for the goal line." My confusion is in the first half. What does isse mean? Is it a variable form of issho? A verb maybe? The verb 'issu' doesn't exist though. Does it only mean what it means coupled with "no se"? What does *that* mean? If you can help, it'd be much appreciated.

Comment: http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%84%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9B%E3%83%BC%E3%81%AE%E3%83%BC%E3%81%A7

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/44326/9831・https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1966/9831

Comment: I just searched Google and found out its a song.  If you are translating a song, it doesn't need to be exactly the same as long as it catches the soul of the line.  Refer to @user3856370 's [link](http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%84%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9B%E3%83%BC%E3%81%AE%E3%83%BC%E3%81%A7) and just use your interpretation to fill in words that sounds good.

Answer (score 2):

いっせのせ is more like "on three" when doing countdowns in the English language. It is not rare in Japan to do countdowns with the phrase "せーの" to time actions together.

Answer (score 1):

I believe いっしょ and いっせいのせ are somewhat different.  いっせいのせ has a meaning of coming together as a team and working in concert (as one unit) together.  I don't believe いっしょ has the same connotation of an almost *coordinated* effort.  Further, it appears that いっせのせ is just a variant pronunciation.  At any rate, your translation seems good to me.  I might just have said it as, "the whole team together makes a break for the goal line" or rather, since I don't know the context, "a goal line which the whole team makes a break for" (technically more correct).

Answer (score 1):

I'd hazard a guess that it comes from 一斉（いっせい）, which is used to mean "everyone together, at the same time". Quick search turned up that the idiom used can be quite different from place to place, and the OP's version is most commonly found in 関東. Over in　関西 apparently いっせーので is used, while in other places, the entire phrase is foregone for such phrases as さんのーがあ、はいっ(九州)

Answer (score 0):

> いっせいのせ
>   is written as "一斉のせ" which is explained in other answers.

"一斉{いっせい}のせ" is a shout when doing something together, where the former "一斉の" is a shout for preparation and the last "せ" is a signal that will be the timing to start the action together. The function of "一斉の" is same as "Get set!" in "On your mark! Get set! Go!" "Go!" or the sound of a pistol corresponds to the last "せ".
The last "せ" comes from the syllable of "せ" in "一斉{いっせい}の".

[image]

Comment: Did you make these own pictures? I am starting to notice. If so, they're really good! :)